# AngularJS : Can a directive template contain a form element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Is it possible to use a `form` element inside an angular directive template? E.g. I might want to fully generate the form to save on repetitive coding - the HTML shows the data, the directive auto-generates the editing. I would find it useful for edit pages that repeat a lot:

```
<div data-editable="true">
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>        
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
.directive('editable',function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       require: '^form',
       transclude:true,
       scope: {}, // to be set after...
       template:'<div><form name="someForm"><span>FORM</span></form></div>',
       link: function(scope,elm,attrs,controller) {
           //nothing here quite yet...
       }
   };
});
```

Yet when I run it, the output does not transclude, and the `form` element is stripped out:

```
<div data-editable="true" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div><span>FORM</span><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div></div>
```

- The `<span>{{item.name}}</span>` is not transcluded in
- The `<form>` element is completely stripped out

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to define the transclude entry point in your template? `template:'<div ng-transclude><form name="someForm"><span>FORM</span></form></div>',`

Comment: Seems, it works http://plnkr.co/edit/afeorwJdCGx3jydMtfA0?p=preview

Comment: Huh! So it does in plnkr, but my jsfiddle doesn't. I need to see why it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, angular directives can contain form elements, and I have used this possibility in practice, though without transclusion.

Comment: OK, so first mystery solved. You are using 1.3.0-rc2. If you try 1.2.x (I tried 1.2.1 and 1.2.13), the `<ng-transclude>` doesn't seem to transclude. The form is still a mystery, though...

Comment: Yes, indeed! It looks like pre-1.3.0, ng-transclude didn't work as an element, only as an attribute, so `<div ng-transclude></div>` works, while `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` does not. I see nothing in the docs about it, but the doc examples only use it as an element beginning in 1.3.0, and your plunkr works with it as an element or attr in 1.3.0 but not 1.2.x.

Comment: Ha! Turned out it was rendering a form inside a form, which is not legitimate. I don't know if the browser stripped it or angular, but that was the problem. I will post the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems here:

1. There was a `<form>` inside a `<form>`, which was stripped out by either the browser or angular (I don't care which).
2. Angular pre-1.3.0 seems to support `ng-transclude` in the template **only** as an attribute. From 1.3.0 onwards it supports it as an element as well.

Comment: FYI.  You can use the <ng-form> directive for nested forms.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm